# Redirect URL paths included with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, redirect

I have seen several questions about redirecting to a page via javascript, and that's great, but all of them just redirect to a base url. I want to include a variable path. So say for instance I have `http://www.glas.com/my/url/path` I want to use `window.location.replace()` to replace the `glas` part only, and change it to `glass`. I'm a beginner at JavaScript so any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var path = ''; // this is where I'm stuck
window.location.replace("http://www.glass.com/" + path);
```

Where the `path` variable would parse the current URL for anything after the `/`. I have tried looking at JavaScript's `match` and `regexp`, but it all seems very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace('glas', 'glass');
```

Comment: *face palms* Wow. Unerringly simple. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('glas','glass');
```